# How to list the root directory content (File.listFiles does not work)

Tags: android

I know that the "standard" way is to call

```
new File("/").listFiles()
```

This method returns null on my device (Huawei P20 lite). I was sure this means the app has no access to the root folder. However, the File Manager For Superusers (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fm.clean.pro) shows the content of the root folder. How does it work?

Important note 1: the device is NOT rooted.

Important note 2: both `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are enabled in the manifest.

Comment: Did you check (new File('/')).isDir()?

Comment: Yes. isDirectory() and canExecute() return true, but canRead() returns false.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I noticed in logs testing such tricks is that you are denied in reading the `/` dir and some other dirs like `acct`. Here's an example of an error message I was getting

```
2022-09-06 00:46:13.552 12202-12202/com.example W/com.example : type=1400 audit(0.0:3231): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="dm-4" ino=2 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c165,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0 app=com.example
```

`denied { read } for name="/"` means you are denied in reading this location

What's interesting is that you can browse some subdirectories without a problem

```java
for (String s : List.of("/etc", "/mnt", "/odm", "/proc", "/system"))
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: " + s + " = " + Arrays.toString(new File(s).listFiles()));
```